# How small do singular values (from SVD) have to be to indicate rank deficiency?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If we compute the SVD of a matrix A, then the SVD of that matrix will have a series of singular values. If the matrix is rank deficient, then some of its singular values may be extremely small. My question: exactly how small do singular values have to be to indicate rank deficiency? I am trying to find some formula (besides some absolute number like 10^-10) that indicates this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mathematically the answer is they must be zero. Numerically there is no simple answer, but generally anything smaller than $\varepsilon_{mach} \sigma_1$ ends up being treated as zero.

Comment: As in, how to detect cases where a matrix is mathematically-speaking exactly rank-definition, but you get a singular value on the order of $10^{-16}$ because of floating-point rounding error?  Or where a value is "zero for practical purposes"?

Comment: @Community Bot **Once again, automatic comment is completely erroneous: the question is crystal clear ! **. Why has such a stupid robot been hired ?

Comment: @James I typically threshold singular values according to their magnitude relative to the largest singular value. In other words, treat $\sigma_k$ as $0$ if $\sigma_k/\sigma_1 < \epsilon$, with $\epsilon = 10^{-10}$ for instance.